# How to create parallel Bootstrap columns by using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to create parallel columns dynamically by using JavaScript, I don't know how to create them though. This is my HTML code I want to create with JS.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <textarea rows="20" cols="50">At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. We offer free tutorials in all web development technologies.</textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <p>Que</p>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="test" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Generally Bootstrap's grid is used for such purposes.

Answer (score 2):

With JS it's not that easy to make it dynamic, since you cannot just append strings (also template literals) to Nodes. You would have to create a Node first, and then add a content and then append and all.

It is quite simple with jQuery though:

```
const appendChild = (content) => {
    $('.row').append(`
        <div class="col">${content}</div>
    `)
}

// don't know where these would come from, maybe you're getting this info form somewhere outside?
const colOne = `<textarea rows="20" cols="50">
    At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. We offer free tutorials in all web development technologies.
    </textarea>
`;

const colTwo =`<p>Que</p>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="test" />
        </div>
    </div>
`;

// wherever you're getting the ones from above, you could call this function directly there
appendChild(colOne);
appendChild(colTwo);
```

[Here's a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jvxkymL6/2/)

--------------------------- EDIT ---------------------------

As mentioned in the comments, it IS possible to do it in VanillaJS, so here's the JS option:

```
const row = document.querySelector('.row')

const appendChild = (content) => {
    row.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
        <div class="col">${content}</div>
    `)
}

// don't know where these would come from, maybe you're getting this info form somewhere outside?
const colOne = 
`<textarea rows="20" cols="50">
    At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. We offer free tutorials in all web development technologies.
</textarea>
`;

const colTwo =
`<p>Que</p>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="test" />
        </div>
    </div>
`;

// wherever you're getting the ones from above, you could call this function directly there
appendChild(colOne);
appendChild(colTwo);
```

And here's the [Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tza38q4w/)

Comment: Actually you *can* append a string to an existing element in HTML, even without the downsides of appending to `innerHTML`. The method is called [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML). (or insertAdjacentText for a text node.)

Answer (score 0):

Use `cloneNode` and then `appendChild` to container.

Pseudo code:

```js
var row = document.getElementByClassName("row")[0];
var container = document.getElementById("container")[0];
var clone = row.cloneNode(true);
container.appendChild(clone);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a bit of an idea on dynamically generating within bootstrap grids.

HTML:

`<div class="container" id="content">`

JS:

```
    let leftColumn = `<textarea rows="20" cols="50">At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. We offer free tutorials in all web development technologies.</textarea>`
    let rightColumn = `
        <p>Que</p>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="test" />
            </div>
        </div>
        `;

    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = `
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            ${leftColumn}
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            ${rightColumn}
        </div>
    </div>
    `;
```